# Using VBA running MySQL select query returns NULL for BLOB field that is not NULL

Tags: mysql, vba

My code used to work I'm not sure what happened. I tried restarting the MySQL service.

Image2 is a blob field in a MySQL database. It has data in it, but shows up as NULL when I try and pull that data out. I can retrieve the data from all other non-blob fields. Anyone know what might be going on?

```
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Server_Name = "xxxx"
Database_Name = "acs"
User_ID = "xxxx"
Password = "xxxx"
table_name = "setcrewreport"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"


SQry = "SELECT * FROM setcrewreport where Serial = '" & Sheets("Contract").Range("B10").Value & "' AND VisitNumber = '1'"
rs.Open SQry, cn

Serial = rs!Serial <-- has data
Image1 = rs!Image2 <-- NULL
```

Comment: See http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/tech-resources/articles/vb-blob-handling.html particularly the section on setting the connection string OPTION parameter - maybe try setting that.

Comment: I have the same issue, win 10 ,32 Bit Office & 32 Bit mysql 8.0 Unicode Driver. tried Ansi Driver -> get Null too. Tried 3.51 Driver -> works, it gets the value (just a String)

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer / workaround for this here:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70765

I tried setting the cursorLocation when setting the ADODB Connection as mentioned there. The Error is now history.

Example:

```
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = connectionString
conn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
conn.Open
```